# Google App Engine Search API giving blank results in Django after upgrading to 1.7.3

Tags: tags, django-templates, full-text-search

After upgrading to GoogleAppEngineLauncher 1.7.3 (1.7.3.333), when receiving a result from the Search API in the django template, the value of each field is displayed as a blank.

Before the upgrade, using the syntax `{{ result.fields.1.value }}`,  it would correctly display the value of the field.

To test, I changed the syntax to: `{{ result.title }}` and it gives the following result:

```
 [search.TextField(name=u'title', value=u'Title of first document')]
```

But if I use `{{ result.title.value }}` it gives blank again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the similar issue while working on it but after few tries i was able to come up with the right solution you can use following option to display data correctly

```
{{result.title.0.value}}
```